# Automating deployment of PHP source from Mercurial Repos to Apache server in CentOS using .sh file

Tags: shell, deployment, mercurial, automation, centos

I have a basic deployment procedure in place and I want to automate it. I need help with creating an sh file that I can call which will take care of all the steps.

Notes about my setup:

- root does not have FTP access.
- Another user 'senthil' has FTP access to its own folder only /home/senthil

Deployment procedure

After I checkin code to bitbucket.org...

1. Open putty, login as `senthil` (type username + password).
2. navigate to repo clone folder `/home/senthil/repos/mysite`.
3. Do `hg pull`.
4. Type password when requested.
5. Do `hg update`.
6. logout of senthil (putty is closed!).
7. Open putty, login as root (type username + password).
8. navigate to repo clone folder `/home/senthil/repos/mysite`.
9. type `hg archive /path/to/website/root`.
10. run a `chmod` command so that apache user has appropriate access

When I tried to make one sh file that will take care of this, I couldn't. I could just make 2 or 3 steps and then I would encounter problems like this:

1. How to enter a password at a prompt through sh for hg pull
2. How to logout and login as another user in putty

How can I automate the whole process in one sh file, that I can run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use single session (I can't see any FTP in process, only local FS)
2. You have to login on host with Plink, which can perform non-interactive logins and run command on server-side after login (command will be tour shell-script with all deploy tasks): `plink HOST COMMAND`
3. In order to avoid password-prompt on pull (but fetch will be better, one command instead of pull+update) you can read about [[auth] section in .hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) (global or repo-specific)

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of ssh for connecting to machines without password.

Google for "ssh for beginners" or checkout this link to learn to do it. 
http://inside.mines.edu/~gmurray/HowTo/sshNotes.html

To answer your second question, for logging out a user, just type the command exit in the command prompt and it should work.